# Connecting to Avaya with DevLink API

Tags: vb.net, connection, avaya

I am trying to connect to Avaya with DevLink sample code which is written in VB. When DLOpen is called it connects successfully but the problem is that when DLRegisterType2CallDeltas() function is called the result is a number greater than 2 something like 432563542633 and it seems there is an issue in connection the output is `"Bhoo!! 432563542633 "`. I read DevLink help but only 3 values are mentioned for the result of DLRegisterType2CallDeltas() just 0 for success and 1 , 2 for error. I really don't know what the value greater than 2 means. Any help please?
The code is below:

```
Public Sub StartMonitor(idPbx As Integer, PbxAddress As String, pbxPassword As String)
        Dim PConn As Connection_Parameter.Connection_Status_Paramenter = New Connection_Parameter.Connection_Status_Paramenter

        Try
            PConn.IdPbx = idPbx
            PConn.ErrorLevel = Connection_Enum.ErrorLevel.info
            PConn.StatusMessage = "Connection in progress..."
            PConn.Status = CommsEvent_Enum.CommsEvent_State.DEVLINK_COMMS_OPERATIONAL

            RaiseEvent ConnectionStatus(Me, PConn)
            Dim iRet As Long = DLOpen(New IntPtr(idPbx), PbxAddress, pbxPassword, Nothing, Nothing, oCommsEvent)

            If iRet = 0 Then
                PConn.StatusMessage = "IpOffice is present!!"
                RaiseEvent ConnectionStatus(Me, PConn)
            Else
                PConn.StatusMessage = "IpOffice is present ?? "
                RaiseEvent ConnectionStatus(Me, PConn)
                'Exit Sub
            End If
            PConn.StatusMessage = "Wait connection response..."
            RaiseEvent ConnectionStatus(Me, PConn)
            Do
                Thread.Sleep(100)
                Application.DoEvents()

            Loop While Not bIsConnect And Not bIsInterrupt

            iRet = DLRegisterType2CallDeltas(New IntPtr(idPbx), oCallLogEvent)

            If iRet > 0 Then
                If iRet = 1 Then
                    PConn.ErrorLevel = Connection_Enum.ErrorLevel.warning
                    PConn.StatusMessage = "Error!! Check ip office IP Address or LAN Connection!!!"
                    RaiseEvent ConnectionStatus(Me, PConn)
                End If
                If iRet = 2 Then
                    PConn.ErrorLevel = Connection_Enum.ErrorLevel.warning
                    PConn.StatusMessage = "Error!! CTI License not found...!!!"
                    RaiseEvent ConnectionStatus(Me, PConn)
                End If

                If iRet > 2 Then
                    PConn.ErrorLevel = Connection_Enum.ErrorLevel.ignore
                    PConn.StatusMessage = "Bhoo!! " & iRet.ToString
                    RaiseEvent ConnectionStatus(Me, PConn)
                End If
                'Exit Sub
            Else
                PConn.StatusMessage = "DLRegisterType2CallDeltas is OK"
                RaiseEvent ConnectionStatus(Me, PConn)
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        Finally
            PConn = Nothing

        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: I run another code written in cpp and the return value is always 2. It seems it has licensing issues. I am still working on it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to have CTI pro license on PBX side to use the Devlink, else you will always get 2 as a result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, as I said in the above comment it is licensing issue